# changing the icon on my website isnt working correctly(FontAwsome)

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

please note:I dont know any html/css/js . this is a premade template and I'm only tweaking it..

Hello,
so im building a portfolio website and i want to showcase my projects by language, for R project I want an R icon and for python a python icon. i use the fa-python for example and all I see is a white circle.. code + photo given below:

```
<span class="icon solid major fa-code" ></span>
```

pic for 1st code: [image]

what I'm trying to do:

```
<span class="icon solid major fa-python" ></span>
```

pic :[image]

Comment: Have you checked the version of font-awesome used in your template? It's possible that the template is using an older version and `fa-python` was not included in that version.

Comment: how do i check the version?

Comment: The font awesome example for python shows a second class `fa-brands`. Have you tried adding that class as well? https://fontawesome.com/search?q=python&s=solid%2Cbrands

Comment: Check the CSS file for font-awesome. It's usually included on top of the file, or in the file name as well.

Comment: @DanielBlack i did, it does not work.

Comment: Font Awesome Free 5.15.4  @artikandri

Comment: According to https://fontawesome.com/v5/icons/python?s=brands , you probably should add `fab` as well.

Comment: @artikandri fab makes the logo show but super small and wont show with  icon solid major, only when I delete it

Comment: You can tweak it by using a different element for the python icon probably, it may got overwritten. Something like <span class="icon major"><i class ="fab fa-python" /></span>, then probably you can take care of the positionings with some additional stylings

Comment: @artikandri separating the lines shows both white circle and logo, not inside

Comment: And that's where you need to adjust the styling a bit. I can't help since I don't have your template, but from my guess, it's either that the fa-python icon got the same color, or that it got overlapped by the circle. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try by using below examples

```
<i class="fab fa-r-project"></i>

<i class="fab fa-python"></i>
```

For your above code, Instead of only using fa-python try using 'fab fa-python'

Comment: this makes the logo show, but only when I don't use the solid icon thing.. i want the white circle and inside the circle I want the language logo

Comment: Have you tried like this ?<span class="icon solid major fab fa-python" ></span>   Do not remove your existing classes ->  icon solid major

Comment: yes it shows a white circle

Comment: can you please share  or add css for classes icon, solid and major class if possible?